# Copy attribute values between same ID features QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, autofields

I'm trying to copy multiple attribute values between two features in a geojson with the same value of another field (like an id).

For example:

- id= 1 field = A

if in another record I repeat id =1 automatically set field = A

I think with autofields plugin I could make something like that but I don´t know how to build the expression I have to use.

Comment: Which QGIS version?

Comment: Hi, i´m in QGIS 2.14 ltr

Comment: @pacuga - How many id values are there?

Comment: Not too many, the idea is to copy the attributes of the rest of the fields. Each "unit" would be a small portion of a large dataset assigned to a technician (such as 200 polygons) but not many with the repeated ID

Comment: @pacuga - If the values for "field" is fixed for each particular id (e.g. `id = 1; field = A`, `id = 2; field = B` etc), then you could create a case statement so instead of copying the values, just let the expression enter them. I.e. `CASE WHEN "id" = 1 THEN A WHEN "id" = 2 THEN B WHEN "id" = 3 THEN C END`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I would have to create that expression dynamically since I do not know the ids I would have previously (users are creating them). It would be something like "if id exits field = field value in that id" the difficulty I have is in constructing that expression.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think one method could be to create a dictionary holding the id keys and their associated values in your field. Then when a user adds a feature and enters the id, the value would be read from the dictionary and added to the field.

So you could use something like the following in the **Python Console** (remember to change the field names accordingly):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
value_dict = {}
id_idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('id')
value_idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('field_name')
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    value_dict[feat[id_idx]] = feat[value_idx]

def update(featureAdded):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        attr = feat.attributes()
        if feat.id() == featureAdded:
            layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, value_idx, value_dict[attr[id_idx]])

layer.featureAdded.connect(update)
```

Then test by adding a feature and entering a known id in your "id" field.

Comment: Thank you Joseph !! Just that solution I thought with a small form and another dictionary for when the feature already exists.
Thanks

Comment: @pacuga - Most welcome! Sorry, are you asking another question?